# Instance of Value Type in Julia

Tags: types, julia

Can I have an instance of a value type in Julia?

When I tried to enter `isa(3, Val{3})` at the REPL console, it returns a `false`.

So what does `three = Val{3}()` give me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you observed, it is indeed possible to create instances of `Val` types, but they bear little relation to the "values" from which you construct them. For example,

```
julia> 3 == Val{3}()
false
```

`Val` types (or `Val` instances) really have only one purpose: to pass information to Julia's compiler, which sees types but (generally) not instances. For example, you can't dispatch on an integer of a particular value:

```
julia> check_for_three(x::Int) = false
check_for_three (generic function with 1 method)

julia> check_for_three(x::3) = true
ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid type for argument x in method definition for check_for_three at REPL[3]:1
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:234
 in macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:92 [inlined]
 in (::Base.REPL.##1#2{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./event.jl:46
```

However, you can dispatch on a `Val` type:

```
julia> check_for_three_val{N}(::Val{N}) = false
check_for_three_val (generic function with 1 method)

julia> check_for_three_val(::Val{3}) = true
check_for_three_val (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> check_for_three_val(Val{2}())
false

julia> check_for_three_val(Val{3}())
true
```

You can write the same code using types rather than instances:

```
julia> check_for_three_valtype{N}(::Type{Val{N}}) = false
check_for_three_valtype (generic function with 1 method)

julia> check_for_three_valtype(::Type{Val{3}}) = true
check_for_three_valtype (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> check_for_three_valtype(Val{2})
false

julia> check_for_three_valtype(Val{3})
true
```

The latter is a little harder on your function-author (you have to type that `Type{}`) but a little easier on the caller (you can skip the `()`). The general convention is to adopt the latter so as to be nicer to the caller, but this is just a convention; either could be chosen.

Finally, `Val` is a fun trick, and sometimes it can be used to solve performance problems, but it's also easy to misunderstand it and indeed make performance worse. See these sections of the manual

- https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-value-type
- https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#The-dangers-of-abusing-multiple-dispatch-(aka,-more-on-types-with-values-as-parameters)

Comment: Thanks @tholy . If I understand right, the type `Val{3}` and an instance `Val{3}()` are useless at run time? Are the functions above evaluated at compile time?

Comment: That's right, their purpose is compile-time evaluation. That's why transitioning between the world of (true) values and `Val` doesn't make sense; since the compiler can't predict true values, you lose all the potential benefits of compile-time evaluation.